# Should I use a temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a report query that is taking 4 minutes, and under the maximum 30 seconds allowed limit applied on us.

I notice that it has a LOT of INNER JOINS. One, I see, is it joins to a Person table, which has millions of rows. I'm wondering if it would be more efficient to break up the query. Would it be more efficient to do something like:

Assume all keys are indexed.
Table C has 8 million records, Table B has 6 Million records, Table A has 400,000 records.

```
SELECT Fields
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON b.key = a.key
INNER JOIN Table C
ON C.key = b.CKey
WHERE A.id = AnInput
```

Or

```
SELECT *
INTO TempTableC
FROM TableC
WHERE id = AnInput
```

-- TempTableC now has 1000 records
Then

```
SELECT Fields
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B --Maybe put this into a filtered temp table?
ON b.key = a.key
INNER JOIN TempTableC  c
ON c.AField = b.aField
WHERE a.id = AnInput
```

Basically, bring the result sets into temp tables, then join.

Comment: If possible, please post the execution plan for the slow query.

Comment: 6-8 million records isnt that big and shouldnt cause a problem on properly indexed tables. I regularly deal with 400 million record tables which perform just fine for queries.

Comment: The execution plan when provided will give insight into where the actual performance overhead is taking place, as well as validate correct index usage. Please share it.

Comment: Thanks chaps - will get it tomorrow. What's the best way to provide it to you?

Comment: @cdotlister - Grab a screen shot of the graphical plan and upload it as an image, or get a text plan and you can then just paste that in as a "quote" text block.

Comment: @cdotlister - Did you manage to resolve your slow query problem? Great if you did but if not get the execution plan posted for people to help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Person table is indexed correctly, then the INNER JOIN should not be causing such a problem.  Check that you have an index created on column(s) that are joined to in all your tables. Using temp tables for what appears to be a relatively simple query seems to be papering over the cracks of an inadequate database design.

As others have said, the only way to be sure is to post your query plan.

Comment: You can do this with getting the query plan.

Comment: It came down to a very silly sub query, which was being run for each row.... Thanks for the help.